# Group/Sort rows with column same value together in groups and order each group by date DESC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table and want to group/sort rows that have same `Name` column value together and then sort each group by `Date` column.

[image]

So, the expected result is like this:

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: It would be great to know what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question properly then try this
**select *  from tbl
group by Name
order by Name,Date**

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the images,but you should try with PIVOT